# Error while 'keystone user-list'

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have installed OpenStack in Ubuntu 12.04.

I am getting this error while executing this command.

```
keystone user-list
```

Error is this.

```
Expecting authentication method via
  either a service token, --os-token or env[OS_SERVICE_TOKEN], 
  or credentials, --os-username or env[OS_USERNAME].
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to source the admin-openrc file that you created with admin credentials.
Refer the open stack documentation for further details
http://docs.openstack.org/icehouse/install-guide/install/apt/content/ch_clients_openrc_files.html